# Question about nested brackets in set theory.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Hello everyone and thank you for reading my question.

I have a question regarding set theory. I have the following sets:

= { { 1 , 2 , 3 } , 1 , 2 ,3 , 4 , 5 }

= { 1 , 3 , 5 , 7 , 9}

They ask me to do the following with the sets: C - D

according to me that would be:    C - D = { { 1 , 2 , 3 } , 2 , 4 }

but some other friends says its:  C - D = { 1 , 2 , 2 , 3 , 4 }

How would I treat the brackets inside  "C" , I mean { 1 , 2 , 3 }  , should I treat it as a Unit or should I treat it like individual numbers?

Thank you for your help.

Regards.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: You are correct.

Comment: So I guess I have to treat  the nested brackets inside the set as a Unit then! :D Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

Let a = { 1, 2, 3 }.
Thus { { 1, 2, 3 }, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }
= { a, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }.
Does that clarify the problem?

Comment: So I guess I-ve got to treat it as a unit then. Thank you very much.